# Java Swing - Place border around JTable row when row has Boolean and String types (Nimbus Look and Feel)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border, tablecellrenderer

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find an answer here.

I have a JTable. I need to place a red border around certain rows that satisfy a certain condition (no value in the Class Type column). When I had only Strings in the JTable, the following code worked. I have since added a Boolean (JCheckBoxes) column in the JTable, causing my code to not put a border around the whole row anymore. How can I fix the code to put a border around the whole row again?

This does appear to be a Look and Feel issue. Using the System LAF (on Windows 10) makes it correctly put a border around the whole row, while using the Nimbus LAF makes it appear as below. I wanted to use Nimbus though, so any advice on fixing this part of Nimbus would be appreciated.

I am using the default renderers provided by Java using NetBeans, as shown in one of the images below. All 4 columns have the Renderer set to "none".

Custom Creation Code in NetBeans for the JTable:

```
new javax.swing.JTable()
{
    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;

        if (rowContainsNonexistentClassType(tableFullClassList.convertRowIndexToModel(row)))
        {
            int top = (row > 0 && isRowSelected(row - 1)) ? 1 : 2;
            int left = column == 0 ? 2 : 0;
            int bottom = (row < getRowCount() - 1 && isRowSelected(row + 1)) ? 1 : 2;
            int right = column == getColumnCount() - 1 ? 2 : 0;

            jc.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(top, left, bottom, right, Color.RED));
        }
        else
            jc.setBorder(null);

        return c;
    }
}
```

What it looked like when the JTable only had Strings:
[image: String-only JTable]

What it looks like with the JTable having Strings and Booleans:
[image: String & Boolean JTable]

The JTable column settings in NetBeans:
[image: JTable column settings in NetBeans]

Comment: Works fine for me. I use JDK8 on Windows 7. See [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for working examples. Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Maybe it is a LAF issue?

Comment: Hmm. Your LAF suggestion is correct. Using the System Look and Feel makes it appear correctly (on Windows 10 anyway), while it appears like in the pictures above if I use the Nimbus LAF. I'll edit my question with info about LAF.

Comment: I would consider that is a LAF issue, i have the same problem when i use Nimbus.

Comment: Any way to get around the issue in Nimbus? I'm looking up ways to modify Nimbus, but it seems limited to customizing sizes and colors. A custom Synth LAF may be the best option.